# Using a list of symbols with tidy-select

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyeval

In our data aggregation pipeline we have a bunch of conditioning variables that are used to define groups. To improve code readability and maintainability, we use a preconfigured list of symbols with tidy evaluation as per this illustrative snippet:

```r
# this is the list of our condition variables 
condition_vars <- rlang::exprs(var1, var2, var3)

# split the data into groups
data %>% group_by(!!!condition_vars) %>% summarize(...)
```

This works great but I can't figure out what would be the elegant way to use this in  `<tidy-select>` context, e.g. for something like `nest`. The problem is that new `nest()` wants something like `nest(data = c(var1, var2, var3))` and not `nest(var1, var2, var3)`, so `nest(!!!condition_vars)` will give me a warning.

The best I could come up with is

```r
df <- tibble(x = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3), y = 1:6, z = 6:1)
vars <- exprs(y, z)
nest(df, data = !!call2("c", !!!vars))
```

but surely there is a better way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `nest(df, data = c(!!!vars))`.

But nowadays, if the expressions are simple column names, I would store them in a character vector. You can supply the character vectors with `all_of()` in selection contexts. In action verbs like `mutate()` or `group_by()`, use `across()` to create a selection context where you can use `all_of()` (and other features like `starts_with()`).

```
cols <- c("cyl", "am")

mtcars %>% group_by(across(all_of(cols))
mtcars %>% nest(data = all_of(cols))
```

Comment: Thank you Lionel, that's exactly what I was looking for! I agree that character vectors would make things more convenient for selection, but there is some custom value expansion we have to do and there the API is simply more convenient using tidy expansion and meta programming...